# Restar restar dos SUM en SQL

Tags: mysql

Supongamos que tengo una tabla muy sencilla en MySQL llamada `record`:

```
    user_id: int, // id del usuario
    type: varchar, // tipo, si es egreso o ingreso
    amount: int // cantidad que quiero restar
```

Y en categorías tengo dos únicamente, ingreso y egreso, donde ingreso sería el dinero que gana al usuario y el egreso el dinero que se les descuenta.

Yo quiero sumar todos los registros que coincidan con *tipo="ingreso"* y restarle la sumatoria de todos los registros que coincidan con *tipo="egreso"*. Y todo esto que coincida con un usuario en particular.

Lo intenté de varias maneras, pero no encuentro una forma indicada de lograrlo.

Acá una de ellas:

```
select sum(s1.result) from 
(SELECT sum(amount) as result FROM mydb.record
where user_id = 1
and type = 'ingreso'
union
SELECT sum(amount * -1) as result FROM mydb.record
where user_id = 1
and type = 'egreso') as s1
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir a tu pregunta **todas** esas maneras que dices haber intentado? Saludos

Comment: Ahi lo ingrese..

Comment: Tu código de ejemplo no coincide con el nombre que decís que tiene tu tabla ni con ninguno de los campos que decís que tiene. Podrías aclarar realmente que tenés o que probaste?

Comment: ups, bueno ya ahi ordene los campos para que coincida

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema (definición) de la tabla `record`? Puedes obtenerlo con un `SHOW CREATE TABLE record`. Nos facilitaría la tarea muchísimo.

Answer (score 2):

Tu código puede simplificarse muchísimo haciendo uso de un `CASE`, de modo que multiplicas por `-1` en un caso, por `1` en el otro y por `0` en cualquier otro caso (no especificas si es un `ENUM` que no pueda tomar ningún otro valor).

Aquí puedes ver el resultado del `CASE` dependiendo del valor del campo `amount`:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN type = 'egreso' THEN -1
    WHEN type = 'ingreso' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END valor
FROM record
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Con algunos datos de ejemplo el resultado sería:

| user_id | type | mount | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ingreso | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | ingreso | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | egreso | 4 | -1 |
| 1 | ingreso | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | ingreso | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | egreso | 3 | -1 |
| 1 | ingreso | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | egreso | 4 | -1 |
| 1 | ingreso | 5 | 1 |

Y aquí la suma o resta teniendo en cuenta el `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(amount * CASE
    WHEN type = 'egreso' THEN -1
    WHEN type = 'ingreso' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) valor
FROM record
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Y éste sería el resultado con esos datos de ejemplo:

| valor |
| --- |
| 15 |

Puedes ver el código SQL en funcionamiento en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v9ZWBo2JUA2YqoNvZwtpVD/0